# Toad debugger does not step into procedure

Tags: debugging, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, toad

I am using Oracle 11g (SYSTEM user). All the debugging buttons are enabled, and I have also enabled the "Toggle compiling with Debug" option, but when I hit the "Trace into" option of debugging it says "Execution has Terminated". This happened when trying to debug a procedure in Toad PL/SQL. Any solutions or idea where I went wrong?

NOTE: Toad version IS Toad for Oracle Xpert Edition 2019 (13.2).

Comment: Did you set break points? Trace into runs until it hits a break point; no break point then no breaks. Try Step Into.

Comment: Not Working with breakpoints also!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to appropriate privileges, e.g. `DEBUG CONNECT SESSION` and `DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE`.

Next, your object must be compiled with debug. The "Toggle compiling with debug" option only affects compiling using the "Execute/Compile statement at caret" button, <kbd>F9</kbd>. If you are compiling using "Execute as script" button, <kbd>F5</kbd>, then you need to have the compile with debug statement in your script, e.g.`ALTER PROCEDURE my_proc COMPILE DEBUG`

You can verify that your object is compiled with debug, or not, by querying `ALL_PLSQL_OBJECT_SETTINGS` and checking the value of `PLSQL_DEBUG`.

You should also consider making a proper user for yourself vs. using `SYSTEM`.